# Filters not working properly

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

I made two filters for my auction web application. I implemented two filters, the first which performs simple logging operations, and the second, which check if the user is authorized to access a particular resource.

The troubles is that These filters work correctly only the first time I connect to the website. Infact it displays the name of the the user in the toolbar, and this happens only if you logged in correctly. Afterwards, I log out and I repeat the process, but the second filter does not work at all.

I put println statements to check if the filters are actually executed, but it isn't the case. The first filter works constantly. The strange part arises when I change the xml mapping. Infact, when I take the mapping out for both filters, the first filter continues working! I went nuts all day yesterday trying to understand this.

Weirder yet, If I rewrite the xml mapping for the filters, they work both for the first log in process, but then, once I log out and repeat the operation, the log in filter doesnt work anymore. To make my web application I am just JAVA7, netbeans 7.2 and Tomcat 7. I fear that this may be a bug with the Netbeans IDEA, but I am not sure.

The xml mapping is the following:

```xml
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<filter>
    <filter-name>FiltroLoggingFumettopoli</filter-name>
    <filter-class>Filtri.FiltroLoggingFumettopoli</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>FiltroLoggingFumettopoli</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>FiltroLogin</filter-name>
    <filter-class>Filtri.FiltroLogin</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>FiltroLogin</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/Registrato/*</url-pattern>
    <servlet-name>IlMioConto</servlet-name>
    <servlet-name>Vendi</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>**
```

Here is the first filter which does the logging in the log fil:

```xml
private void doBeforeProcessing(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (debug) {
        log("FiltroLoggingFumettopoli:DoBeforeProcessing");
    }


    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;


    this.log(httpRequest.getRemoteHost()+" is trying to access page: "+httpRequest.getRequestURL()+
                " il "+TimeUtility.ottieniDataOra()+". "+filterConfig.getFilterName());
    System.out.println("FILTRO FILE DI LOG----> LOGGING OCCURED IN LOG FILE: "
            +httpRequest.getRequestURL()+" il "+TimeUtility.ottieniDataOra()+". "+filterConfig.getFilterName());
}    

private void doAfterProcessing(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (debug) {
        log("FiltroLoggingFumettopoli:DoAfterProcessing");
    }
}


public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    doBeforeProcessing(request, response);

    Throwable problem = null;
    try {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch (Throwable t) {

        problem = t;
        t.printStackTrace();
    }

    doAfterProcessing(request, response);


    if (problem != null) {
        if (problem instanceof ServletException) {
            throw (ServletException) problem;
        }
        if (problem instanceof IOException) {
            throw (IOException) problem;
        }
        sendProcessingError(problem, response);
    }
}
```

here is the filter which checks if it is an authorized user who wants access to the resources that are contained in the Registrato folder, and a few servlets:

```xml
public class FiltroLogin implements Filter
{    
private FilterConfig filterConfig = null;

public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig)
{
    this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response, 
     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
{

    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    HttpSession sessione = httpRequest.getSession();

    ServletContext sc = filterConfig.getServletContext();

    String filterName = filterConfig.getFilterName();
    String servletPath = "Servlet path: " + httpRequest.getServletPath();

    String url ="";

    Utente user = null;
    user = (Utente) sessione.getAttribute("utente");
    if(user == null){

        Cookie[] cookies =httpRequest.getCookies();
        String email = CookieUtility.ottieniValoreCookie(cookies, "userCookie");
        if(email.equalsIgnoreCase("")){               
            System.out.println("FILTRO LOGIN----->NESSUN COOKIE TROVATO!");
            System.out.println("FILTRO LOGIN----->SERVLET CONTEXT: "+sc.getContextPath());


            url ="/MostraInserzioni";
            httpResponse.sendRedirect(sc.getContextPath()+url);
            return;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("FILTRO LOGIN----->COOKIE TROVATO: "+email); 
            user = UtenteSql.cercaUtente(email);
            System.out.println("FILTRO LOGIN----->UTENTE TROVATO: "+user.getUsername());
            sessione.setAttribute("utente", user);     
            String salutoUtente = "Benvenuto "+user.getNome();
            sessione.setAttribute("messaggio", salutoUtente);

        }
    }
    else
        System.out.println("FILTRO LOGIN----->USER FOUND: "+user.getUsername());


     sc.log(httpRequest.getRemoteHost()+" cerca di accedere alla risorsa: "+httpRequest.getRequestURL()+
                " il "+TimeUtility.ottieniDataOra()+". "+filterConfig.getFilterName());
    System.out.println("FILTRO FILE DI LOG----> LOGGING OCCURED IN LOG FILE: "
            +httpRequest.getRequestURL()+" il "+TimeUtility.ottieniDataOra()+". "+filterConfig.getFilterName());
    chain.doFilter(request, response);

}

public void destroy()
{
     filterConfig = null;
}
}
```

Comment: `getSession()` is `getSession(true)`, hence creates a new session when not present. You could do `getSession(false)` and `user = sessione == null ? null : ...`. Only in `else` then create a session.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Since this is my first project, is it alright if you explain your answer in further detail? I understand the part getSession(true) but in null: ... , what Should i put exactly there? And could you explain to me why my progams, the way its stands now, behaves the way it does?

Comment: Simply `user = sessione == null ? null : (Utente) sessione.getAttribute("utente");` and after `else {` just: `sessione = httpRequest.getSession(true);` Prevents holding sessions for non-users.

Comment: I got it! I would have never guessed this, to be fair, and the professors in my university don't really care for helping either. Anyways I did what you said, with a little modification, but I think it's what you prettty much explained, since now my web app works!

Comment: HttpSession sessione = httpRequest.getSession(false);
if(sessione == null){
            System.out.println("FILTRO LOGIN----->USER NOT FOUND IN SESSION!");

Comment: Then I checked the cookies. If I find the cookie i need i simply create a new session and put the USER info in the session , otherwise i simply redirect to  the login page

Answer (score 1):

Simply `user = sessione == null ? null : (Utente) sessione.getAttribute("utente");` and after `else {` just: `sessione = httpRequest.getSession(true);` Prevents holding sessions for non-users. *– Joop Eggen yesterday*

```
HttpSession sessione = httpRequest.getSession(false);
if (sessione == null) {
    System.out.println("FILTRO LOGIN----->USER NOT FOUND IN SESSION!");
```

*– Salvatore Servodio 44 mins ago*

Then I checked the cookies. If I find the cookie i need i simply create a new session and put the USER info in the session , otherwise i simply redirect to the login page